# How to select which URL should redirect to Android browser from WebView?

Tags: android

I have a WebView and I  load a web page in to it. I want to choose which link's on that page should open in WebView and which should open in Android browser. I can make them all open in WebView by using WebViewClient and overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...). 
I have tried something like:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.toLowerCase().contains("yahoo.com")) {
            return false;
        } else {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
         }
```

,but that is not working. Any Ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not completely clear:

> If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application
>   handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles
>   the url.

I'm assuming `WebViewClient` refers to the `WebView view` parameter.

I would try returning true and firing a new intent to handle the url.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

startActivity(intent);

return true;
```